# How can I change the length of a hex number?

Tags: php, hex, substr, string-length, unique-id

I have a function who generates a Hex number:

```
function generateUid(){
    $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
    $uuid = $uuid->getHex();
    $uuid =  substr($uuid,8);

    return   $uuid;
}
```

The hex has the length of 25 but I want to cut it to only 8 digits.

Comment: @user3783243 Do you mean `substr($uuid,0,8);`?

Comment: Wow, yes, it is working! happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `substr` first parameter is where to start, and second is the length (number of characters to return). So:

```
substr($uuid, 0, 8);
```

Should start at the first position and return 8 characters.

Your previous code:

```
substr($uuid,8);
```

started at the 9th character and returned the rest of the string.